# Centos set default ftp directory for a user

Tags: centos, ssh, ftp

I am setting up accounts for people to connect to the server through ssh and SFTP.
When I test the login, it goes straight to the "/" directory, and I do not want that to happen. I want to make it so they can only go inside a certain folder and access anything inside of those.

I have done the following commands:

```
groupadd developers

useradd -G developers tom

usermod -d /root/server/gamed tom
```

I thought it worked, but when I used WinSCP to test it. It still went to the root directory.

Comment: What FTP server are you using? What options are set in there? If you're using vsftpd and have `chroot_local_user=YES` in your config, then it will APPEAR to be / in the FTP client, even though they are actually in `/root/server/gamed`.

Answer (score -1):

You can set users default path in `/etc/passwd`

open /etc/passwd

```
vipw /etc/passwd
```

search for a user and change to a desired path:

```
user_name:x:504:504::path_to_user_directory:/bin/bash
```

Comment: You should never edit this file directly (or shadow, or groups). Instead, use `vipw`, which performs syntax checking, possibly saving you from locking you out of your system.

Comment: What's the risk? did it many times without any side effects.

Comment: I read something about in the `sshd_config` you can do a `Match Group developers` and then set a `ChrootDirectory` I tried that and when I went to restart the sshd it failed and said `Bad Configuration... Match` the version of my OpenSSH is 4.3p2. Is there ANY way I can upgrade it to a newer version to make the 'Match Group developers' work?

Comment: Introduce an inadvertent syntax error and your system auth breaks.

Comment: Or some system command modifies the file at the same time, with different locking semantics, and one of your changes gets lost.